# Adding validation in RequestMapping annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-annotations

I am using spring boot and I want to add API versioning support for some of the RequestMapping (url path should start with /v[1-9]+/).

I am thinking of creating an annotation: MyRequestMapping that additionally supports the api versioning path. This way, anyone using MyRequestMapping will automatically have api version assigned to it.

As I can not extend RequestMapping annotation (annotation extension is not allowed in Java), I am not sure how to go forward with this approach.. Any hint/idea will be great!

**In short: How do I support api versioning for "path" in RequestMapping? Thanks..**

Comment: When you are using Spring rest, then you will get a 404 for a URL when you don't have that Request mapping defined in any of our Controllers, is there something else you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks.. I edited the question to make it more clear: How do I introduce a custom validation check for "path" in RequestMapping

Answer (score 0):

I would create class-only MyRequestMapping that matches URLs starting with /v[1-9]+/

See https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates  for official documentation about using regex in request mapping

Then user could further narrow down the path with method-level RequestMapping annotations.

Comment: Thanks.. thats fine but my question is: how to add the check for url in RequestMapping?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `filter` , and do the required check inside `filter` . If the check didnt return true just modify  the `httpresponse` from the filter itself and return, Thats it. I added a sample `filter` below, you need to do required changes in `web.xml` or `@configuration` class accordingly, for the filter to work.

```
 public class MyFilter implements Filter {

        public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
                throws IOException, ServletException {
if("")//Do the required check here
{
//Modifiy httpservlet response .
}
            filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found better way to support api versioning. Below is the explanation:

1) **Create an annotation: ApiVersion:**

```
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@RequestMapping("/{apiVersion}")
public @interface ApiVersion {

    /**
     * version
     *
     * @return
     */
    int value() default 1;
    boolean latest() default false;
}
```

2) **Create custom RequestCondition** to put the matching logic:**

public class ApiVersionCondition implements RequestCondition {

```
private final static Pattern VERSION_PREFIX_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("/v(\\d+)/");
private final static Pattern LATEST_PREFIX_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("/latest/");

private int apiVersion;
private boolean latest;

public ApiVersionCondition(int apiVersion, boolean latest) {
    this.apiVersion = apiVersion;
    this.latest = latest;
}

/**
 * Latest definition will take effect, that means method definition will override the classes definition
 *
 * @param otherApiVersionCondition other condition that is matching.
 * @return latest definition of matching condition.
 */
public ApiVersionCondition combine(ApiVersionCondition otherApiVersionCondition) {
    return new ApiVersionCondition(otherApiVersionCondition.getApiVersion(), otherApiVersionCondition.isLatest());
}

/**
 * Define matcher to match the pattern for api versioning.
 * When version number requested is equal to or greater than configured, condition will be returned.
 *
 * @param request Request instance
 * @return ApiVersionCondition based on match
 */

public ApiVersionCondition getMatchingCondition(HttpServletRequest request) {
    Matcher m = LATEST_PREFIX_PATTERN.matcher(request.getRequestURI());
    if (m.find() && isLatest()) {
        return this;
    }

    m = VERSION_PREFIX_PATTERN.matcher(request.getRequestURI());
    if (m.find()) {
        Integer version = Integer.valueOf(m.group(1));
        if (version >= this.apiVersion)
            return this;
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * When more than one configured version number passes the match rule, the bigest one will take effect.
 *
 * @param otherApiVersionCondition other api version condition that was satisfied.
 * @param request                  Request instance
 * @return 1 if other version condition has greater api version, -1 if this condition has greater api version, 0 if they are same.
 */
public int compareTo(ApiVersionCondition otherApiVersionCondition, HttpServletRequest request) {
    return otherApiVersionCondition.getApiVersion() - this.apiVersion;
}

/**
 * Getter for api version.
 *
 * @return api version for the condition.
 */
private int getApiVersion() {
    return apiVersion;
}

/**
 * Getter for whether latest is configured in annotation.
 *
 * @return true if latest is configured in annotation, else false.
 */

private boolean isLatest() {
    return latest;
}
```

}

3) **Create custom RequestMappingHandlerMapping:**

```
public class ApiVersioningRequestMappingHandlerMapping extends RequestMappingHandlerMapping {

    @Override
    protected RequestCondition<ApiVersionCondition> getCustomTypeCondition(Class<?> handlerType) {
        return createCondition(AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(handlerType, ApiVersion.class));
    }

    @Override
    protected RequestCondition<ApiVersionCondition> getCustomMethodCondition(Method method) {
        return createCondition(AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(method, ApiVersion.class));
    }

    private RequestCondition<ApiVersionCondition> createCondition(ApiVersion apiVersion) {
        return apiVersion == null ? null : new ApiVersionCondition(apiVersion.value(), apiVersion.latest());
    }
}
```

4) **Ask Spring to use the custom RequestMappingHandlerMapping:**

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcRegistrationsConfig implements WebMvcRegistrations {

    @Override
    public RequestMappingHandlerMapping getRequestMappingHandlerMapping() {
        ApiVersioningRequestMappingHandlerMapping apiVersioningRequestMappingHandlerMapping = new ApiVersioningRequestMappingHandlerMapping();
        apiVersioningRequestMappingHandlerMapping.setOrder(0);
        apiVersioningRequestMappingHandlerMapping.setRemoveSemicolonContent(false);
        return apiVersioningRequestMappingHandlerMapping;
    }

}
```

5) **Use it in controller:**

```
@ApiVersion //default is version 1
//@RequestMapping("{apiVersion}/test") //add this if want to specify a common root e.g. v<x>/test for all below request mapping
@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    private static final String template = "Hello , %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")    // URI: /v1/greeting will be mapped to this method
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "World") String name) {
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
                String.format(template, name));
    }

    @ApiVersion(2)
    @RequestMapping("/greeting")    // URI: /v2/greeting will be mapped to this method
    public Greeting greetingV2(@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "World version 2") String name) {
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
                String.format(template, name));
    }

    @ApiVersion(value = 3, latest = true)
    @RequestMapping("/greeting")    // URI: /v3/greeting OR /latest/greeting will be mapped to this method
    public Greeting greetingV3(@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "World version 3") String name) {
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
                String.format(template, name));
    }
}
```

There are still some fine tuning to do but this is a good start for what I wanted to achieve. Will update if find better idea or some improvements. Please let us know if someone finds improvements.